# Amazon Code Catalyst Localhost Development

Tags: aws-codecatalyst

I recent created a project using the modern three-tier web application blueprint from AWS Code Catalyst. I can commit and push changes without errors, and the changes show up in the fully deployed web instance. However, full deployment takes 10-15 minutes, and for simple UI / data processing changes, I would like to debug/view these changes locally without fully redeploying the application. Does Code Catalyst support local development within an IDE (I am using VS Code) or do I need to select a different blueprint for my project. I am using Lambda for my compute platform and Amplify for the frontend hosting option. I haven't modified the Modern three-tier web application blueprint otherwise beyond adding a new Mysfit (which was successful) per the tutorial.

I am trying to use npm commands, and npm run preview run within the /web folder will generate a static front-end, but I can't figure out how to also load in our data to be able to edit everything locally.

I tried to make front-end UI changes locally, but refreshing the page locally does not display changes.